# How to open html page in dialog in Vuetify? - VueJS

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, vuetify.js

I tried to open a different page in vuetify, using `window.open (http://url)` and after an action return to the primary window to update it with some data.
However, I need to open the page in a modal. And `window.showModalDialog()` isn't work

I am using the following features:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "devour-client": "^1.4.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "papaparse": "^4.3.3",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-rc.27",
    "vue": "^2.2.6",
    "vue-i18n": "^7.0.5",
    "vue-kindergarten": "^0.3.0",
    "vue-moment": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-router": "^2.5.3",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^2.0.0",
    "vuetify": "^0.12.7",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^4.1.2"
  },
```

I am making an Oauth2 to Clio App connection, using a backend as a middleware that generates the authentication token.

Any idea of how to open an html page in a dialog and return to the primary window, updating data?

Answer (score 8):

what about using the Vuetify v-dialog component, and for its content, have an iframe with your HTML page? Like [this](https://codepen.io/lshapz/pen/zRBPBz).

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="100%">
 <v-btn color="primary" dark slot="activator">Open Dialog</v-btn>
  <v-card>
   <iframe style="width:100%" src="https://vuetifyjs.com"></iframe>
  </v-card>
 </v-dialog>
```

Comment: I like that, I am about to do the same thing for my OAuth auth code grant thing.